# ORA-04091: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it error during execution of oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, sql-insert

I have below trigger in which for `FIELD_NAME` field i want to insert value into `FIELD_TRACKING` table as `'Deactivation time of KPI in case of Downtime(Select KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT FROM KPI_DEFINITION)'`. The bracket part in this string value comes from `KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT` field of `KPI_DEFINITION` table. So below is the trigger i have wrritten for this. The trigger compile without any error. But when i try to change the `DNTM_REAC_AFTER_HRS` field from the `KPI_DEFINITION` table then i am getting error `ORA-04091: table RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` `ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.TRG_TRK_KPI_DEFINITION'`.

```
create or replace TRIGGER RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION."TRG_TRK_KPI_DEFINITION" AFTER UPDATE ON RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION
      FOR EACH ROW

    IF NOT  :old.DNTM_REAC_AFTER_HRS=:new.DNTM_REAC_AFTER_HRS THEN
        INSERT INTO RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.FIELD_TRACKING  (FIELD_TRACKING_ID,TABLE_NAME,TABLE_ID, FIELD_NAME,FIELD_OLD_VALUE,FIELD_NEW_VALUE,USER_ID, TIMESTAMP, FIELD_TRACKING_COMMENTS)
        VALUES (FIELD_TRACKING_SEQ.NEXTVAL,'KPI_DEFINITION',:new.KPI_DEF_ID,'Deactivation time of KPI in case of Downtime'|| '(' || to_char((Select KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT FROM KPI_DEFINITION)) || ')',to_char(:old.DNTM_REAC_AFTER_HRS),to_char( :new.DNTM_REAC_AFTER_HRS),:new.LAST_UPDATED_BY,:new.LAST_UPDATED_DATE, decode(:new.KPI_ACTIVE_DOWNTIME,'N','This KPI has been reactivated on end of a downtime.',''));
      END IF;

    END;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trigger cannot read the table (Select KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT FROM KPI_DEFINITION), that changes... you can access the value in this way: :new.KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT.
More info: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm

In other cases you can try to do it in [autonomous transaction](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems002.htm):

```
create or replace TRIGGER RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION."TRG_TRK_KPI_DEFINITION" 
AFTER UPDATE ON RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  -- ...
  COMMIT; -- don't forget it!!!
END;
```

Comment: yes i make that change now its showing the actual error and the error is single row query returns more than one row.

Comment: How many rows does return this query: Select KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT FROM KPI_DEFINITION ?

Comment: it returns more than one row . I have fixed this issue but now the issue is as i have more than 50 fields and if statement do i need to provide commit inside each if statement ? Because as soon as i declare PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION and does not commit then it gives an error as error saving changes to table "RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION"."KPI_DEFINITION":
Row 1: ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back

Comment: Yes you have to commit it in this case... have you thought about using DBMS_JOB instead of this trigger?

Comment: ohh ok. I just add the commit at the bottom of my trigger before END and not inside each and every if statement. And its working but it will not cause any issue right ?

Comment: This is completely separate transaction, do some experiments: update KPI_DEFINITION and rollback transaction... now select changes from FIELD_TRACKING (yes, they are still there).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90326/discussion-between-imagine-and-rahul).

Comment: i have messaged you in chat

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this error is: Triggers with "for each row" is "row level" trigger and it can only see that row.

The solution is to use autonomous transaction (so that the action DML is at another transaction, not bound by the trigger limitation), or you can use statement level trigger (remove "for each row" at declaration).

Answer (score 0):

Since you need informations from the table for which you created your trigger for(Select KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT FROM KPI_DEFINITION), you can get the KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT from the reference **:NEW** as it represents the new row (**:NEW.KPI_FREQ_TIME_UNIT**).